# I can't change InputType of EditText after I set it to TYPE_NULL

Tags: android, null, android-edittext, input-type-file

I set the InputType of an EditText to TYPE_NULL with:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

I can set it to TYPE_NULL, it works! But if I want to set InputType to something else, like TYPE_CLASS_TEXT, it doesn't work!

How can I change it dynamically in code? Like to TYPE_NULL, then to TYPE_CLASS_TEXT and to TYPE_NULL again?

Comment: I have the recycler view with a list of Edit texts. The InputType of the EditText depends on the functionality of EditText. Some have the click functionality to select the data from dialog. So they have InputType null. But in the recycler view if the InputType of EditText is null then I'm not able to update the InputType to Text. Because of recycling, uses the already created views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Try this one

**activity_main1.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtValue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enable Input" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity1**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

    private Button btnClick;
    private TextView txtValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

        txtValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
        btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

        txtValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(txtValue.getInputType()==InputType.TYPE_NULL){
                    txtValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    txtValue.invalidate();
                    btnClick.setText("Disable Input");
                }else{
                    txtValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                    txtValue.invalidate();
                    btnClick.setText("Enable Input");
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

To do this you first have to change the **INPUT TYPE**, then add text to it dynamically as follows.....

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: i tried it already the same. but it dosn't work! i can't change it from null to text! keyboard doesn't pop up when i click on edittext, after i changed the inputtype from null to text!

Comment: then instead of InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT , use InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL

Comment: omg. InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL ALWAYS changes EditText... ALWAYS. before it is on full screen EditText and after InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL it is default edittext. why?